# Проблема с перемещением окна WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

Попробовал сделать кастомную "шапку" в WPF. Знаю, что затея не всегда нужная, но я хочу разобраться. Нагуглил ответы, однако не работает, так как задумано. Я пробовал использовать `WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"`, однако тогда окно перестает перемещаться, почему, я не понимаю, а при значении `False` все работает как надо, но кнопки в зоне `WindowChrome` не работают.

```
<Window x:Class="Адскаая_дрочильня.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Адскаая_дрочильня"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="630" Width="1120" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        Background="#2e2e2e" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" 
        MinWidth="800" MinHeight="450"
        WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="Menu">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00000000"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10, 1, 10, 1"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#d2d2d2"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Uni sans"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Menu button"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,5,10,5"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#5e5e5e"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="App">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00000000"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="X"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#f3f3f3"></Setter>
            
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome>
            
        </WindowChrome>
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource Menu}"/>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource Menu}"/>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource Menu}"/>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource Menu}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource App}"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource App}"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource App}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF4B4B4B"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: `WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome` должно быть на кнопке (или любом другом объекте, на который надо кликать), а не на окне.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, большое спасибо! Добавил `<Setter Property="WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome" Value="True"/>` в нужный стиль.